# Limit laws how to write an integral as a max of a sum

Tags: exponential-function, limsup-and-liminf

Good Morning, I am not able to prove following equation:

lim 1/n log()=...
https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/koenig/www/GA.pdf
Korollar
1.3.2

I thought about doing a Laplace Transformation, but I sucked. Furthermore, I tried to change dx to a Dirac- measure to connect it to the Varadhan's Lemma (the rate function is 0). I would like to use the senctence stated above (Lemma
1.3.1), but it didn't work. How can I write an integral as a sum?

Kind regards,
mimi

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please write down the equation in your question, or at the very least provide the page number in the text you link to.

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate the integral by Riemann sums:

$$\int_0^1e^{nf(x)}\,dx\approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ne^{nf(x_k)}$$,

where it is assumed that the interval $[0,1]$ is partitioned into $n$ intervals of length $1/n$ each, and $x_k$ are points chosen from the partition-intervals. Then you can use the lemma, together with an additional argument, to conclude the result given as korollar 1.3.2.